# Tweaked Casting vs. Casting Math.Floor

Tags: java, c#, casting

The other day I thought about this. If we want to cast `double` to `int` retaining `Math.Floor` behavior and without worrying about overflow, why don't we cast them normally and do a simple check to get the same behavior as `Math.Floor`?

I went ahead and made this method in C#:

```
public int TweakedCast(double num)
{
    int ret = (int)num;
    if (ret > num)
        ret--;
    return ret;
}
```

From my testing, `TweakedCast(num)` gave at most half the time of doing `(int)Math.Floor(num)`.

I have a lot of questions.
Is this a viable way to do `double` to `int` casts without worrying about overflows?
Would the result be the same (i.e. in both methods) for all numbers, even for `NaN`, `PositiveInfinity` and `NegativeInfinity`?
Would using `TweakedCast` have any disadvantages?
Why did `TweakedCast` take at most half the time? Is it because `Math.Floor` is designed for doubles?

I would also like to know if this code will do the same when using it in Java, since I don't have the right setup to do the testing.

Comment: If you're concerned about overflow then just run the code in a `checked` block when doing the cast.

Comment: I clearly said I'm not concerned about overflow, I already know about that.

Comment: If you're not concerned about overflow then just perform the cast and nothing else; you'll already have your intended behavior.  The `floor` is entirely superfluous, which is of course why adding it is going to take longer.

Comment: @Servy - Yes, assuming positive values. For negative values, the floor will decrement by one compared to the cast.

Comment: @Servy casting truncates the decimal part. It has the same result as rounding to zero. However, `Math.Floor` rounds to negative infinity.
e.g.  
4.623 will result 4 in both casting and `Math.Floor`, but -2.321 will result -2 in casting and -3 in `Math.Floor`

Answer (score 0):

Since nobody has got an answer, I tested a bit and got these results.

I made this benchmarking program to see if the results are always the same:

```
class Program
{
    // all the code is unchecked, overflow is not important.
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        Random rand = new Random();

        // Check random numbers (positive and negative) and see if they are the same on both function.
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            double num = (rand.NextDouble() + rand.Next(10000)) * (rand.NextDouble() >= 0.5 ? 1 : -1);
            Console.WriteLine("TweakedCast({0}) = {1}", num, TweakedCast(num));
            Console.WriteLine("Math.Floor({0}) = {1}", num, Floor(num));
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        Console.WriteLine("TweakedCast({0}) = {1}", double.PositiveInfinity, TweakedCast(double.PositiveInfinity));
        Console.WriteLine("Math.Floor({0}) = {1}", double.PositiveInfinity, Floor(double.PositiveInfinity));
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("TweakedCast({0}) = {1}", double.NegativeInfinity, TweakedCast(double.NegativeInfinity));
        Console.WriteLine("Math.Floor({0}) = {1}", double.NegativeInfinity, Floor(double.NegativeInfinity));
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("TweakedCast({0}) = {1}", double.NaN, TweakedCast(double.NaN));
        Console.WriteLine("Math.Floor({0}) = {1}", double.NaN, Floor(double.NaN));
        Console.WriteLine();

        double a = rand.NextDouble() + rand.Next(10000);
        double b = -(rand.NextDouble() + rand.Next(10000));

        Console.WriteLine("a: {0}, b: {1}", a, b);
        Console.WriteLine("After 25 million iteration of both a and b on both methods, the result is:");
        sw.Start();
        for (int i = 0; i < 50000000; i++)
        {
            TweakedCast(a);
            TweakedCast(b);
        }
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("TweakedCast time: {0}", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        sw.Restart();
        for (int i = 0; i < 50000000; i++)
        {
            Floor(a);
            Floor(b);
        }
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Math.Floor time: {0}", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static int TweakedCast(double num)
    {
        int ret = (int)num;
        if (ret > num)
            ret--;
        return ret;
    }

    static int Floor(double num)
    {
        return (int)Math.Floor(num);
    }
}
```

**result:**

```
TweakedCast(-7668.35019480127) = -7669
Math.Floor(-7668.35019480127) = -7669

TweakedCast(-3737.06628523304) = -3738
Math.Floor(-3737.06628523304) = -3738

TweakedCast(-8627.20293022795) = -8628
Math.Floor(-8627.20293022795) = -8628

TweakedCast(9332.33679385313) = 9332
Math.Floor(9332.33679385313) = 9332

TweakedCast(-6910.65257059767) = -6911
Math.Floor(-6910.65257059767) = -6911

TweakedCast(Infinity) = -2147483648
Math.Floor(Infinity) = -2147483648

TweakedCast(-Infinity) = 2147483647
Math.Floor(-Infinity) = -2147483648

TweakedCast(NaN) = -2147483648
Math.Floor(NaN) = -2147483648

a: 9772.35618077747, b: -945.045879946577
After 25 million iteration of both a and b on both methods, the result is:
TweakedCast time: 2326
Math.Floor time: 4317
```

**Answering my questions:**
1- `TweakedCast` is a viable way to get the floor as an integer, as long as the `double` is inside the boundaries of `int.MinValue` and `int.MaxValue`.

2- The result will be the same in both `Math.Floor` and `TweakedCast` for almost all the values. The only exception being `double.NegativeInfinity`, which would be returned as `int.MaxValue` in `TweakedCast` and as `int.MinValue` in `Math.Floor`, most probably because of the checks made by `Math.Floor`.

3- The only disadvantages I found was the fact that it only works between `int.MinValue` and `int.MaxValue` and the fact mentioned in the previous answer about `double.NegativeInfinity`.

4- I don't have a definite answer for this, but my guess is that the algorithms used are different, and the checks at the beginning of `Math.Floor` might have a small effect, too. In addition, `double` has double the size of an `int`, although this is also least likely to have effect.

**Note:** I searched in the code of a popular video game made in Java, they had an utility class for faster math functions, and there was exactly the same method for floor that used casting and a simple check. This proves that `TweakedCast` would work perfectly for java.